# Back button handler working on every screen after changing drawer navigator in react - native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am making a react native application in which there can be two type of user model and member.Now each having different `drawer navigator` as both having different data and both these drawer are inside a main `stack navigator` which is main navigator for the application. Now in both the both the `drawer navigator` .

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Splash : { screen: Splash },
  PrivacyPolicy : { screen: PrivacyPolicy},
  Welcome : { screen: Welcome },
  Login : { screen: Login },
  HomeMember: {screen: memberdrawerNavigator},
  HomeModel: {screen: modeldrawerNavigator},
  OtpChangePassword : { screen: OtpChangePassword},


}, {
     headerMode: 'none',
     initialRouteName: 'Splash'

})
```

I have a homepage different for both the member type and in both the home page i have implemented the back handler like this.

```
 handleBackWithAlert = () => {

  if (this.props.isFocused) {

            if(this.state.loading_status){
                   this.setState({loading_status:false})
            }

          else{
                  Alert.alert(
                  'Exit App',
                  'Exiting the application?',
                  [
                  {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                    style: 'cancel'
                  },
                  {
                    text: 'OK',
                    onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()
                  }
                  ],
                  {
                  cancelable: false
                  }
                );
          }

return true;
}
}



componentWillMount() {

BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackWithAlert);
//this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();

}

componentWillUnmount() {
 BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackWithAlert);

}
```

Since i wanted to check back handling on only specific page so i exported my component like this.

```
export default withNavigationFocus(HomePage);
```

Now what the problem is that suppose i am using member account and after that i logout and then login with model account then this back handler is working on every screen why ? And if i close or kill that app without logout and restart then this problem disappears.

Here is my code called on logout

```
 AsyncStorage.clear()
ToastAndroid.show("Logged Out Successfully !",ToastAndroid.SHORT);

              const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Welcome' })],
              });
              this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, something is wrong with your `BackHandler` listeners. maybe you're not removing `BackHandler` listener on `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: U can see the code componentWillUnmount() {
 BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackWithAlert);

}

Comment: I think you should give a try to SwitchNavigator, It will reduce complexity and you'll be able to handle back button easily.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html